# Can we make such matlab code so that every time we run the program it will return the same randomly generated matrices?

Tags: matlab

I want to compare efficiency of two iteration methods for computing inverse of a matrices. I want to test performance of these methods on some randomly generated matrices. I want to know can we make such matlab code so that every time we run the program it will return the same randomly generated matrices. Could anybody answer me? I would be very much greatfull to you.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the new versions, use `rng('default')` to set the seed for the random number generator.

In older versions, it is something like `rand('seed','twister');` but I don't remember exactly.

Either way, the first method is recommended by MATLAB.

Edit: here is code to generate random matrix of size $100$

```
n=100; %size of matrix
rng('default'); % set random seed to matlab default
A = rand(n,n); % generate random matrix
```

If you run this same code multiple times, you will get the same `A` each time.

Comment: Dear i want to generate 100*100 random matrices. I want the same matrix to come every time i run the program. How to do? Thanks

Comment: @srijan: Same matrix, or same matrices?

Comment: @srijan See my edit for specific code to generate the same matrix multiple times.

Comment: @RodCarvalho I want same matrix to come every time I run the program....

Comment: @srijan: Then create a random matrix, store it, and every time you need the same "random" matrix use the stored one. What you want, apparently, is not a random matrix, but an *arbitrary* matrix for testing purposes.

Comment: @Daryl Dear I am getting: undefined function or method 'rng' for input arguments of type 'char'...

Comment: In that case, your version of matlab is older than mine. Replace that line with the alternative I give in the description above for older versions of matlab.

Comment: @RodCarvalho How can i store matrices of higher order? I want to test two methods on the same random matrices say of order 1000*1000...I don't know how can i store them so that i may use them...

Comment: You can save it to a .mat file with the commane save [filename] [variables] where I have used square brackets to indicate where you should type your respective parameters. To load them again, use the load command. See [save](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/save.html) and [load](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/load.html).

Comment: @Daryl thank you very much dear.